# how to detect images not use in host

Tags: php, jquery

I have a picture upload module. I don't know how to make a script can be do this: after upload 1 day, I want check images upload to be use or not. If not use I want it will do some action..

Comment: Your question needs _far_ more detail, hence why it's being close-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you serve the images through php, just set up a counter in a database.

If you serve them directly with a link, process the web server acccess log.